# Oauth2.0 | How to manage user session in Single Page application running in an iframe?

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, single-page-application, openid-connect, access-token

I'm new to security domain, and recently I have learned about Oauth2.0/OpenID connect and JWT tokens. I have an existing REST based web application where I need to implement security.

**Server**

*Application A*: Spring boot back-end application sever, with some RestEndpoints exposed connected with Mysql database.

**Front End**

*Application B*: Spring boot Web Applicaiton which have some JSP pages for login and some other template features(Also connected with same Mysql database used by back-end server).

*Application C*: Inside application B we have an Iframe in which Angular app is running, angular app calls the back-end server and show data.

Also in future we want to use SSO for our application as well.

**Current Security**

At the moment we don't have any security on back-end server (i.e We can simply call RestEnd points without any authentication), Application B has basic login security implemented via spring security. User logins on application B and then he/she can use application C (Angular) as well. User session is managed at Application B, when session expires users forced to logout.

**Oauth2 Authorization**

What we are trying to acheive is make the server (Application A) as Oauth2Resource server and Oauth2Authorization server. Application B (JSP front end) remove database connection from it as well as the login controller, application B will call oauth2 server for authorizing user with "password" flow, when application B will receive access_token and refresh_token it will then somehow pass it to Iframe (angular app) to store these tokens inside cookie and on every subsequent request to server angular will add access token to it.

I've read articles about that Oauth2.0 have deprecated the use of "Implicit Flow", and they prefer to use the "Authorization Code Flow". I am having a very hard time to understand how this flow can be used for single page applications(SPA like angular). Also where to store the access_token and refresh_token if I use the implcit flow? I'm aware that storing both tokens in cookies is not a good practice.

Also how to manage user session now? what I have gathered so far is that, on requesting resource server with Bearer access token, when we get unauthorized response, we'll then request for new access token with help of refresh token, but in case when refresh_token is also expired I will force user to login screen. Is this right approach?

Sorry for the long context, any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A couple of recommendations:

- Use a low cost cloud Authorization Server, eg Azure or AWS
- Focus on building great UIs and APIs, which is not easy

In terms of flows, use the Authorization Code Flow (PKCE) and the [OIDC Client](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js) library to manage SPA security.

A good starting point might be my [First Tutorial](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/24/basicspa-overview/) to understand how to get integrated. Generally:

- SPAs use short lived access tokens and should store them in memory
- SPAs traditionally do not use refresh tokens directly

Feel free to post back follow up questions and I can point you to additional resources. You should aim to avoid running the SPA in an iframe by the way - see my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63155081/refused-to-display-login-microsoftonline-com-in-iframe-in-asp-net-mvc-app).